# how can i store html tags in mongo data base and display in ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have post my html elements to data base like this

```
 <article>
      <h1> <span> text editors</span></h1>
        <h2>برامج بنستخدمها عشان نكتب الكود بتاعنا وفي اضافات كتيرة بتسهل الشغل بتاعنا -</h2>
        <h2>  
         <a target=_blank href="https://atom.en.uptodown.com/windows">Atom</a> وتاني برنامج هو  <a target=_blank href="https://code.visualstudio.com/download">VS Code</a> عندك برنامجين حلويين جدا اول برنامج -
        </h2>
        <h2><a target=_blank href="https://code.visualstudio.com/download">للتحميل اضغط هنا</a> VS Code في الشرح بتاعنا هنستخدم -</h2>
        <h2>زي الفيديو وبعد نفتح البرنامج عادي install بعد كدا هنعمل -</h2>
    </article>
```

and I have get these data to my website. I need away to display the html in ejs. I tried many things but nothing works. I tried to dom-parse and it returns one element.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to store complete elements in your DB, cause you might need to change the styling or the structure later.

What you can do instead, is store the data inside each of the tags in your DB, fetch the data when your site loads, and then add it to the elements.